# Matlab array of audioplayers

Tags: matlab, labview

I am creating a matlab script inside labview. Inside that script I try to create an array of audioplayer objects. However, I got an error, and I can't find a way around it.

This is the script:

```
nrOfSounds = 11;
if (exist('p') == 0)
    [snd, freq, bps] = wavread('sounds/1.wav');
    p = audioplayer(snd, freq);
    for t=2:nrOfSounds
        [snd,freq,bps] = wavread(strcat('sounds/',num2str(t),'.wav'));
        s = audioplayer(snd,freq);
        p(end+1) = s;
    end
end
```

And this is the error:

```
Audioplayer objects cannot be concatenated.
```

It seems that I can't create an array of audioplayer objects, but I can't really find a way around this since I'm not really experienced with matlab. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use cells, not arrays.

```
nrOfSounds = 11;
if (exist('p') == 0)
    [snd, freq, bps] = wavread('sounds/1.wav');
    p{1} = audioplayer(snd, freq);
    for t=2:nrOfSounds
        [snd,freq,bps] = wavread(strcat('sounds/',num2str(t),'.wav'));
        s = audioplayer(snd,freq);
        p{end+1} = s;
    end
end
```